# How to pass a variable into an exec statement?

Tags: python

```
for i in range(5):
    do = 'print(image_label+i)'

exec(do)
```

I want it so that instead of printing `image_label+i` it prints `image_label0` and `image_label1` As of now all it does is print `imagelabel+1`.

Comment: Why do you need `exec` for this, exactly?

Comment: its part of a bigger program

Comment: i just took this one piece out

Comment: Your question currently does not show any research effort; questions _must_ show research effort. There are plenty of questions on Stack Overflow about how to put variables into strings; please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: is it possible to pass a variable into an exec statement

Comment: `do = f'print(image_label{i})'`

Comment: Have you read the documentation on [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)?

Comment: @AlimanAhmed: Yes, by passing the variable into the string that is being passed into the `exec` function. Try searching `[python] string formatting`; there are over 37,000 results.

Comment: its says Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\CS work\i.py", line 6, in <module>
    exec(do)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Process returned 1 (0x1)        execution time : 0.143 s
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: yeah but i couldn't find anything on it

Comment: @AlimanAhmed: Strings and integers cannot be added to each other. You can convert an `int` to a string using the `str()` function, and then add it to the string.

Comment: That makes more sense the what you claim the code in your question does (which is incorrect).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that I question the entire purpose of this call to `exec`, but if you really want to do this, then you can suffix the variable name using string interpolation.

```
image_label0 = "foo"
image_label1 = "bar"
image_label2 = "fizz"
image_label3 = "bazz"
image_label4 = "xog"

for i in range(5):
    exec(f'print(image_label{i})')
```

```
foo
bar
fizz
bazz
xog
```

Comment: that's seems to have fixed the issue. i didnt do the curly brackets surrounding the "i" and so that why it didnt work for me

Comment: and i needed it because i want to use use a loop to create new labels for the main program and create them as class variables so i just added self infront of image_labels

Comment: def sort_by_price(self):
        box = 250
        list = []
        finlist = []
        for i in range(5):
            newb = 'image_label'+str(i)
            list.append(newb)
            setattr(self, list[i], QLabel('hello'+str(i),self))
            exec(f'print(self.image_label{i})')
            exec(f'self.image_label{i}.setGeometry(10,{box},50,50)')
            exec(f'self.image_label{i}.show()')
            box= box + 50
that now allows me to create new labels that i can manipulate with other functions